Inner Product Spaces Exercise
I have this exercise: "Let $M$ is a CLOSED subspace of Hilbert space $H$. Prove that $x\perp M \Leftrightarrow \left \| x \right \|_{H}=d(x,M)=\underset{y\in M}{\inf}\left \| x-y \right \|_{H}$. Is that statement true if we omit the closeness of $M$?"
I can exactly prove "$x\perp M \Leftrightarrow \left \| x \right \|_{H}=d(x,M)=\underset{y\in M}{\inf}\left \| x-y \right \|_{H}$". I really want to prove: If we omit "M is a CLOSED", the statement below will wrong, but I have no idea. I have tried to choose $H$ as $\ell^2$ or $L^2(\Omega)$ (where $\Omega$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$), in contrast, I cannot think more.
Hope everyone help me. Thanks so much.

If I am not mistaken, the equivalence is true without assuming closedness of $M$. If $M$ is not closed then there might be no non-zero $x$ that satisfies one of the two conditions.

Yes, it's true. This is due to the fact that $M^\perp = \overline{M}^\perp$ and $d(x, M) = d(x, \overline{M})$. As such, each condition is equivalent to the same condition with $\overline{M}$ replacing $M$.

@TheoBendit So if I want to prove: it is not necessary to carry the condition "M closed", I will prove that:
"For ANY subspace $M$ of a Hilbert space $H$, $\left|x\right|=d(x,\bar{M}) \Leftrightarrow x \perp \bar{M}$". Is that right?

@TrầnNguyênKhang Yeah, but I'd put it like this:$$|x| = d(x, M) \iff |x| = d(x, \overline{M}) \iff x \in \overline{M}^\perp \iff x \in M^\perp.$$

@TheoBendit And the final step of this problem, I want to say like this, is that ok? "If we omit the closeness of $M$, the statement below is still correct, since we can replace $M$ by $\bar{M}$"

I think that's fine.

Let I think more. :D
